# create a mask in material node editor using rotoscope

Tags: materials

in material editor (node editor), i'm trying to use multiple image texture and multiple uv. But having problem whenn trying to combine them, i use mix node , but i can only input another image to be used as masking or alpha channel. I want to be able to create the mask within the blender using rotoscope. So i can do paint to create the masking, but how to use roto as mask? the mask/roto only can be loaded in compositing , but not in material node editor. This shoulb be made available in material , so i can easily isolate or do organic mask to the image texture.

So far , to achieve this, I have to first sent the image texture to the compositing then do the masking and merging  and sent back the output to the material. This is a slow workflow. I should be able to access roto inside the material editor or even better to have a 'compositing' node inside the material editor so i can do compositing right inside the material editor without have to jump back and forth between compositig and material editor.

Any thoughts ?

Comment: You cannot use mask as it is a downstream source. It is only available to Blender after it renders the 3D scene. In fact the devs tell me that it is to hard to rasterise a mask to screen space on 3D view, sorry. You would have to create a mask for each source before loading it via file browser. I know that this does not afford much flexibility

Comment: I have tried using another object's outline as a source for a mask but that is quite difficult as well.

Comment: Thanks , maybe as a good reference : I use Nuke for daily compositing task and this workflow works really great in Nuke where the integration between 2d and 3d space is very good , for exampe i can edit rotoscope spline of 2d masking even in 3d viewer  as if it's a 3d object. This can be a very good example for dev to add this feature.

Comment: Oh I agree it would be a killer function but I was told that it would not be added, probably because Blender doesn't want to be a a 3D compositor like Nuke is.

Comment: Yeah, actually  i'm not expecting to go far like that :-) , maybe just looking the ability to rotoscope the texture inside material node editor. I'm too lazy to go to photoshop. So far i can make it work by using blender compositor  , the only problem is when trying to combine 2 different resolution,  it's hard to control the mask/roto.

Comment: Yes its a pain as the roto is rendered at scene resolution instead of matching to source resolution. Even when using the movie clip editor I think that the mask ignores the source dimensions.